# tiny mce toolbar icons conflict with jQuery UI icons

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce

I have a div with another div holding three icons from JQuery UI. Inside parent div, there is a tiny mce instance. When I click on any button of tiny mce, it is moved down and it its place, JQuery UI's icon is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this, by explicitly referring to the element using Id. Previously, I used class names to refer to the elements. We should use Ids as far as possible to refer to any element.